# Macro issue and what may be the output?

Tags: c, macros, operators, increment

```
#define CUBE(x)(x*x*x)
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    b = 3;
    a = CUBE(b++)/b++;
    printf(a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a confusion in this Macro defining statement? and I need output too?

Comment: what is the confusion ?

Comment: Routine old undefined behaviour...what's the canonical question that this is a duplicate of?  You can't modify `b` four times between sequence points and expect to get anything sane.  Strictly, you can't invoke `printf()` without a prototype in scope either – you don't show the `#include <stdio.h>` line.  However, that usually works.  The `(b++*b++*b++)/b++` nonsense has no answer that you can expect — you can find what a specific compiler does, but it's under no obligation to do anything sane.

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
CUBE(b++)
```

will be converted to

```
(b++ * b++ * b++)
```

which is undefined behavior or problematic due to modifying a variable in one single statement. It's recommended to avoid such a thing.

Try to pass a variable without `++` or `--`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=CUBE(b++)/b++;  

      |  
      V  


a=(b++ * b++ * b++)/b++ ;
```

In the above expression b value modifies between sequence points  would cause undefined behavior due to lack of [Sequence_point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

To avoid this first assign and then increment

```
   a=CUBE(b)/b;
   b++;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `#define CUBE(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))` to avoid mistake when `x` is an expression.
2. `a = CUBE(b++)/(b++);` The value of a after executing the statement depends on the compiler you use or something else. This is called `undefined behavior`.